# Error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 3: did not find expected key

Tags: python, django, docker, heroku, docker-compose

I have a docker application prepared. Now I would like to implement it on a server heroku, unfortunately an error is returned to me during the command execution.

```
git push heroku master
```

I receive this error message

```
Enumerating objects: 466, done.
Counting objects: 100% (466/466), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (442/442), done.
Writing objects: 100% (466/466), 10.30 MiB | 1008.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 466 (delta 83), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: === Fetching app code
remote: 
remote: =!= Build failed due to an error:
remote: 
remote: =!= validate step: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 3: did not find expected key
remote: 
remote: If this persists, please contact us at https://help.heroku.com/.
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to powerful-cove-75131.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/powerful-cove-75131.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/powerful-cove-75131.git'
```

My **heroku.yml** file looks like this

```
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
  web: gunicorn pvb.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://blog.heroku.com/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) the indentation is not matching. It should be like this,

```py
    setup:
      addons:
        - plan: heroku-postgresql
          as: database
    build:
      docker:
        web: Dockerfile
    release:
      image: web
      command:
        - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    run:
      web: gunicorn pvb.wsgi
```

Comment: I fixed it, I had one wrong wsgi name,
After changing to the correct one, I didn't add it to the git.

Comment: @yellowhand glad to hear! yes I have checked the yaml again with a linter and seems fine in both cases!